# Cómo mostrar una opción seleccionada con Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, select, materialize

Estoy desarrollando una web con Vue.js y Laravel. Me he topado con un inconveniente:

Quiero mostrar un formulario que me sirva para edición de una tabla, por lo que deseo mostrar los datos que ya estaban almacenados en dicho formulario. Todos los datos se muestran de manera correcta excepto el del campo "Género", el cual se debe mostrar en una etiqueta .

Para los estilos, estoy usando Materialize.

El código que he usado es:

```
<select required v-model="genero">
    <option disabled>Género</option>
    <option :selected="genero===0" value="0">Femenino</option>
    <option :selected="genero===1" value="1">Masculino</option>
</select>
```

La variable 'genero' puede ser 1 en caso sea hombre o 0 en caso sea mujer. He visto que en la cosola, dicho valor se asigna correctamente en la variable, pero en el navegador no se muestra seleccionada dicha opción.

¿Cómo podría hacer que se muestre seleccionado el campo según los datos ya almacenados en la BD?

Comment: Debes hacer una replica de tu código exponiendo tu caso, si temes mostrar tu código o simplemente ponerlo, porque con ese fragmento no podemos determinar que paso estas haciendo mal.

Comment: tal vez no sea del mismo tipo, pon solo :selected="genero==0" :selected="genero==1" ( dos "=" )